# Unable to play audio file using url in my application in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, media, avaudioplayer, audiokit

[audio link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1trgYAJr7odwcuGhpmIa7KKsjgMxKVl6-/view?usp=sharing)

I uploaded a recording in my google drive link(mentioned above) and set that to public. I am trying to play the audio using audio kit and other audio player(**cocoapods**) with url, downloading the file and play and I tried converting to other formats nothing worked for me. I am unable to play it. This audio is not playing in safari browser also. The recording is done from the web platform and the generated audio format is .opus

Comment: The link is pointing to a website and not to the file itself. I don´t think you can handle it this way. You need a setup where the link is pointing to the file itself and the server allows direct download.

Answer (score 0):

Try please the code below and tell me if is working for you.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
    fileprivate let seekDuration: Float64 = 10
    
    @IBOutlet weak var labelCurrentTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelOverallDuration: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playbackSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        initAudioPlayer()
    }
    
    //call this mehtod to init audio player
    func initAudioPlayer() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://argaamplus.s3.amazonaws.com/eb2fa654-bcf9-41de-829c-4d47c5648352.mp3")
        let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        
        playbackSlider.minimumValue = 0
        
        //To get overAll duration of the audio
        let duration : CMTime = playerItem.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        labelOverallDuration.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: seconds)
        
        //To get the current duration of the audio
        let currentDuration : CMTime = playerItem.currentTime()
        let currentSeconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(currentDuration)
        labelCurrentTime.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: currentSeconds)
        
        playbackSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        playbackSlider.isContinuous = true
        
        player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
                self.playbackSlider.value = Float ( time );
                self.labelCurrentTime.text = self.stringFromTimeInterval(interval: time)
            }
            let playbackLikelyToKeepUp = self.player?.currentItem?.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp
            if playbackLikelyToKeepUp == false{
                print("IsBuffering")
                self.playButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
            } else {
                //stop the activity indicator
                print("Buffering completed")
                self.playButtonOutlet.isHidden = false
            }
        }
        
        //change the progress value
        playbackSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playbackSliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
        
        //check player has completed playing audio
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishedPlaying(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: playerItem)}
    
    
    @objc func playbackSliderValueChanged(_ playbackSlider:UISlider) {
        let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value)
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 1)
        player!.seek(to: targetTime)
        if player!.rate == 0 {
            player?.play()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func finishedPlaying( _ myNotification:NSNotification) {
        playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "play"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        //reset player when finish
        playbackSlider.value = 0
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1)
        player!.seek(to: targetTime)
    }
    
    @IBAction func playButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("play Button")
        if player?.rate == 0
        {
            player?.play()
            self.playButtonOutlet.isHidden = true
            playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "pause"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        } else {
            player?.pause()
            playButtonOutlet.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "play"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }
        
    }
    
    func stringFromTimeInterval(interval: TimeInterval) -> String {
        let interval = Int(interval)
        let seconds = interval % 60
        let minutes = (interval / 60) % 60
        let hours = (interval / 3600)
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
    }
    
    @IBAction func seekBackWards(_ sender: Any) {
        if player == nil { return }
        let playerCurrenTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
        var newTime = playerCurrenTime - seekDuration
        if newTime < 0 { newTime = 0 }
        player?.pause()
        let selectedTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
        player?.seek(to: selectedTime)
        player?.play()
    }
    
    @IBAction func seekForward(_ sender: Any) {
        if player == nil { return }
        if let duration = player!.currentItem?.duration {
            let playerCurrentTime = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
            let newTime = playerCurrentTime + seekDuration
            if newTime < CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
            {
                let selectedTime: CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(newTime * 1000 as Float64), timescale: 1000)
                player!.seek(to: selectedTime)
            }
            player?.pause()
            player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a DEMO:
https://github.com/florentin89/PlaySongFromExternalSource

Comment: Thanks for the efforts Florentin Lupascu. It is working with the audio url provided in the code. Here main issue is with my url the audio file present in the url is issue, Are there are any audio converters I can work on??.